# Excel VBA - move chart series to the end of the table

Tags: excel, vba

I need help with the below code:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overall Performance").Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("$B$8:$BI$11")
```

My table is as follows:

I tried to modify code to `ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("$B$8:$BI$11" & LastRow)` buy it doesn't do anything.

How to modify this code to automatically select all the missing data in my table? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question 2 days ago? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54593490/move-chart-series-by-one

Comment: Hi Pᴇʜ. As posted it again as the code and solution I wanted to use is a bit different than before. I've deleted a previous question now though. Thanks anyway

Comment: I still recommend to use formatted tables, so the chart adjusts to the table automatically and you don't need to fix anything by VBA at all.

Comment: It's great solution Pᴇʜ and I would definitelly recommend it, thank you. The only problem with this report was that it was set up this way by somebody else before and my task was to fully automate it via VBA. The good new is, I have now managed to find a solution via VBA and will post it below soon. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news, I managed to find a solution to my query by using the CurrentRegion property (thanks Pᴇʜ for improving my code). Hope this helps everyone facing the same problem.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overall Performance").Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("$B$8:$BI$11").CurrentRegion
```

Comment: note that you can remove `.Offset(0, 0)` because it doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: Ok, will try to remove it and run it again. Thanks

Comment: I mean `.Offset(0, 0)` tells VBA to move `0` rows and `0` columns from the `CurrentRegion` which means don't offset at all, which *must* be the same as not to call `.Offset` at all ;) *just faster*.

Comment: You're absolutely right Pᴇʜ, I have now removed the Offset property and it does the same job :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("$B$8:$BI$" & LastRow)
```

Where I assume LastRow holds the row index of the last relevant row

You can set LastRow as follows:

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlup).Row
```

Comment: Thanks for getting Back to me @DisplayName. I've tried your code but it does select everything down, instead of the correct and required columns. My code is as follows: `Dim lastRow As Long
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("$B$8:$BI$" & lastRow)` I also tried to sligltly modify code as `Dim lastColumn As Long
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
lastRow = Cells(Columns.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Column
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("$B$8:$BI$11" & lastCol)` but also no luck with it

Comment: What’s the value of lastRow?

Comment: Value is 28/01/2019 (cell BM8). I will be actually running my macro on a weekly basis and I need a range of this table to be updated with the new data every time I run my macro.

Comment: If you set lastRow as “LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlup).Row” then its value is an integer one, namely the column B last not empty cell row index